# Finding word frequencies - without counter

Tags: python, python-3.3

I'm a beginner learning Python 3.3 through http://GrokLearning.com

My objective is to write a Word Counter program that reads multiple lines of plain text from the user, then prints out each different word from user input with a count of how many times the word occurs. All input will be lowercase words only - no punctuation or numbers. The output list will be in alphabetical order.

The program does not accept any submission with Counter or Collections. When I submit solutions found on Stack Exchange with Counter, the editor just pretends the Counter code doesn't exist.

This is what I have so far:

```
all = []
count = {}
line = input("Enter line: ")
while line:
    word = line.split()
    line = input("Enter line: ")
    for w in word:
        count[w] = word.count(w)
for word in sorted(count):
    print(word, count[word])
```

**The problem with my code: if a word is repeated on multiple lines, the code will only count occurrences on the last line the word appeared (instead of total occurrences).**

```
> this is another test test
> test test test test test
> test test test
> 
another 1
is 1
test 3
this 1
```

*I know I did not utilize my list "all". I had tried all.append(word) to make a list of all words the user entered, but my code counted 0 (perhaps because the last line needs to be empty to end the while loop?)*

For reference, I have gone through all of the free modules, but not any of the paid ones. Forgive me: since my knowledge is limited, please explain your answer in simple terms.

Comment: Aside: `all` is the name of a very handy built-in, and so not a good choice for a variable name.  (Plus it's a little nonspecific anyhow.)

Comment: Hint: you have to check if w is already in count, and if so, add to the count, rather than setting the count.

Comment: what you want to have is `setdefault` method on dictionary, and `+=` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in here:

```
for w in word:
    count[w] = word.count(w)
```

In your code, you don't **add** to your count. Instead, you **reset** the count every time you encounter a word. For example, if `count['this']` was 1 before, the next time you encounter it, you set the count to 1 again instead of adding 1 to it.

The second problem is with the expression `word.count(w)`. It is a count of how many times a word appears on a line, at the same time, the loop iterate through every words. That means if you correctly update (instead of reset) your count, you will be counting too many.

For example, if the line has three *'test'*, then you will be updating the count by 3 x 3 = 9.

To fix the problem, you need to address two cases:

- If a word is already in the count (i.e. you have seen that word before), then increase the count by 1
- If the word is not in the count, this is the first time you see it, set the count to 1

Here is a suggestion:

```
for w in word:
    if w in count:
        count[w] += 1
    else:
        count[w] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, @Hai, for your simple, easy-to-understand solution and clear explanation! My first question painlessly answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try following the logic of your program on paper and see what jumps out at you.

- User enters multi line text
- loop through each single line

  - set counter to number of occurrences of 'word' in the *current* line
  - move to next line
- loop through found words

  - print word and its frequency

So for every reading of a line you are setting your counters to new values without taking the older lines into account.

How would you address that 'bug' on paper? How would you then apply that different logic to your program?

Answer (score 2):

Shortest fix and fastest code:

```
for w in word:
    count[w] = count.get(w, 0) + 1
```

The `get` method returns the value associated with the key, or the second optional parameter if the key did not exist. (If second is not specified, and the key is not defined yet, `None` is returned). Thus counts for all words that never existed default to `0`. Then for each word encountered, the count is set to the previous count + 1.

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution! It really helps when I learn multiple ways to solve a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in your `for` loop

```
if w in count:
    count[w] += word.count(w)   # word already in dictionary, update the count
else:
    count[w] = word.count(w)    # word not in dictionary, add count for first time
```

Comment: Adding by `word.count(w)` is adding too much. See my answer for reason.